# Button (.primaryAction in Toolbar) is not displayed correctly in scrollview on two specific Watch (watchOS) devices

Tags: button, watchos

In my already published app, there is a display error on two individual devices that I cannot reproduce. The button (.primaryAction in Toolbar) is correctly embedded in a ScrollView and works in the simulator, on my own two Apple Watches and apparently on the devices of thousands of others.
But the problem is real for one subscriber with two devices with different Apple IDs and the latest versions of the app and watchOS.
This is how it should work:

[This is how it should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzVYD.gif)

This is what the error looks like:

[This is what the error looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBB4Y.gif)

In my opinion, the code is not the reason.
Do you have any idea what could be causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to reproduce the subscriber's error: I had to activate the slider in Settings > Accessibility > Zoom and the button behaved like in the video. If I switch it off and restart the app, the button behaves as it should again.

This may also help one or two others who have such a problem.